# Явная инициализация полей структур с++

Tags: c++, инициализация

недавно услышал про такой термин, как явные инициализаторы, но по запросу в гугле ничего не выдает. Не могли бы вы объяснить, что это такое?
Add: Я имел ввиду такую конструкцию `MyStruct a{.field = 1, .field2 = 2}`, просто там где я это увидел ( не помню где точно ), человек назвал это так

Comment: Забудь. Просто кто-то плохо знает C++ и названия вещей.

Comment: Я думаю что `int a = 1;` можно считать явным инициализатором. А вот что тогда считать неявным)))) не могу сказать. Явный, это когда явно написали, оно что написано то однозначно и будет происходить. А неявный - когда скрыто. Конструктор может вызываться неявно. Оператор может вызываться неявно. А может ли инициализатор вызываться неявно... не думаю.

Comment: Можно хабр почитать https://habr.com/ru/company/jugru/blog/469465/

Comment: @nick_n_a нельзя так считать, иначе начнётся хаос с C++. У такой инициалтзации есть вполне конкретное название.

Comment: думаю, просто имелось ввиду "явная инициализация".

Comment: @nick_n_a, вот такая штука `MyStruct a{.field = 1, .field2 = 2}`, меня интересует. Просто там где я это увидел это называлось явным инициализатором, но возможно я что-то путаю. Сейчас отредактирую вопрос

Comment: @KoVadim, отредактировал вопрос, извините за неточности

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, извините за неточности, отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Вот, нашёл этот [пост](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/438492/) на хабре. Цитирую: `Вот вам и родственники. Явные инициализаторы не поддерживаются в C++ до C++20. Это стандарт C++, который планируется к выходу в 2020 году`. Извините если я что-то напутал

Comment: @n1kzzz это designated initializers. Подробнее: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization